# ggplot order of geom_point and geom_line differ

Tags: r, ggplot2

When using setting the order of factor levels manually, I can't get both geom_point and geom_line to plot the data in the same order.

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(rep(c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25), 2)),
                 B=c(81, 86, 89, 94, 99, 81, 86, 89, 94, 100),
                 C=c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5)))
df$C <- factor(df$C, levels=c(1,0))

colors=c("red", "black")

ggplot(df, aes(A, B)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=C)) +
    geom_line(aes(color=C)) +
    scale_color_manual(values=colors)
```

[image]

I want the 0's from C to be plotted last, which geom_line is doing, but geom_point is not. I don't understand why. How can I get them both to cooperate? If I don't set the factor levels of df$C and rather use dplyr::arrange(desc(C)), it still doesn't solve the discrepancy.

I'm using my own color palette, but even using the default colors, I get this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "the 0's from C to be plotted last"?

Comment: The data from group 0, as denoted by column C. Wanted them to be plotted after the points from group 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your data frame prep to sort the data frame by `C` so that the 0's appear last and get drawn last (i.e. on top) by `geom_point`.

```
df <- df[order(df$C),]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked. My mistake when using dplyr::arrange(desc(C)) earlier was that I applied that after setting the factor levels for df$C. [order] seems to work before or after setting the factor levels.

I'm still curious about why geom_point and geom_line have different behaviours here.

Comment: Super helpful answer - fixed a confusion I had for a while in a simple way, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the colors coming in

```
library(tidyverse)

colors=c("black", "red")

data.frame(A = c(rep(c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25), 2)),
           B = c(81, 86, 89, 94, 99, 81, 86, 89, 94, 100),
           C = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5))) %>% 
  mutate(C = factor(C)) %>% 
  arrange(C) %>% 
ggplot(aes(A, B, color=C)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values=colors) + 
  guides(color = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))
```

[image]

Comment: The OP is looking for the 0's from C to be plotted last, i.e. on top, for both the line and the points.